# Getpass input Python 3

Tags: python

I am trying to create a password input. I am aware of `getpass.getpass` but when I put it into my idle it through up an error saying 'password may be echoed' which it was.

My code:

```
import getpass

p = getpass.getpass()

print("You entered:") + p
```

This may not work as I am using Python 3.2.3

Comment: `print("You entered:" + p)` or `print("You entered:" + str(p))`

Comment: I really like the phrase "it thought up an error".

Comment: @AvinashRaj: `getpass.getpass()` return a string, so no need `str()`. However I think OP's asking about why does `getpass.getpass()` say *password may be echoed*.

Comment: I tried your code (with a corrected `print()`) and it doesn't give me an error.

Comment: Relevant: [Is there easy way to prevent echo from input?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17520292/953482)

Comment: the last line should say `print("You entered:", p)` instead. just ran over this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`getpass`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html) documentation:

> **Note** If you call getpass from within IDLE, the input may be done in the terminal you launched IDLE from rather than the idle window itself.

And also:

> If echo free input is unavailable `getpass()` falls back to printing a warning message to stream and reading from `sys.stdin` and issuing a `GetPassWarning`.

So probably you just don't have a `echo free input` available in your IDLE environment (e.g., you didn't start it from a shell).

Comment: Also about `exception getpass.GetPassWarning`: *A UserWarning subclass issued when password input may be echoed.*

Comment: @KevinGuan: I just didn't want to quote almost all the sentences in the doc page, but yes ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you have problems with getpass() [and quite a few people do] try passwordbox from easygui ver. 0.96. I would strongly advise against 0.98, though. It generetated an error while running the code, contrary to 0.96, which worked brilliantly, showing only asterisks in the box, as desired.

```
python setup.py install

from easygui import passwordbox
password = passwordbox("PASSWORD:")
```

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: But I did! However, I was scolded for duplicating the answer from my other post and it was deleted by the admin. My answer was just 3 sentences, so "including the essential parts" would really mean quote the whole lot, which got the post deleted in the first place... I don't get it. When I wrote how I solved the problem, it got deleted. When I left a link to the solution, it's considered a poor quality answer.