# echo user input in shell as "*" or something similar

Tags: python, passwords, echo, user-input

i am trying to make a sign up and login systen and i would like the user to see '***********' when they enter their password instead of 'Password123', for example.

```
with open("UandP.txt", "a") as x:
    x.write(input("Enter a username: "))
    x.write(",")
    x.write(input("Enter a password: ") + "\n")
```

i would like the input from '`input("Enter a password: ")`' to echo in the shell as '`*`' but i cant use `getpass()` as it doesn't work in the shell

Comment: I have no issues with `pwd = getpass.getpass()` working in the shell. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34396842/getpass-input-python-3 for more information about echoing. That might point you in the right direction. I would not recommend masking the input; you technically expose the password length by doing so.

Comment: As artomason's link says, the behaviour of `getpass` depends on the terminal it's running in. Which terminal are you using? But anyway, at best, `getpass` can only blank passwords, it doesn't do asterisks.

Comment: There are some suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27631629/masking-user-input-in-python-with-asterisks But they might not work on your terminal.