# How to make the user exit the program on a passowrd program in python

Tags: python

Can someone try to help me make with this, please. So once the user guesses 3 times the entire program closes, but once the user gets it wrong it doesn't make them exit the program. Yes I'm aware that I'm asking the same question again but I haven't got my question answered yet so please can someone help.

[image]

Here's another one I'm trying out. Any Suggestions on how to do exit the program if the user gets a certain number of attempts by trying to guess the password wrong. I've been trying to use sys.exit and exit()but it hasn't been working for me, so maybe you can try to that , (but remember my teacher wants it so that it on **IDLE**).

```
Counter=1
Password=("Test")
Password=input("Enter Password: ")
if Password == "Test":
    print("Successful Login")
    while Password != "Test":
        Password=input("Enter Password: ")
        Counter=Counter+1
        if Counter == 3:
            print("Locked Out: ")
break
```

Comment: please copy the code as text in your post and not in an image

Comment: Move the counter check into the loop

Comment: @JosephYoung can you send me a screenshot of the corrected version please that would be much appreciated thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
counter = 1
password = input("Enter password: ")
while True:
    if counter == 3:
        print("Locked out")
        exit()
    elif password == "Test":
        print("That is the correct password!")
        break
    else:
        password = input("Wrong password, try again: ")
    counter += 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. My teacher said that he wanted something so that it would "physically" shut down the program, is this the closest way of forcing the user to get of the program, or no? I heard about:  sys.exit(1)

Comment: exit() is almost the same of sys.exit()

you can put exit(1) if you want you program to return with an error code

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the condition `counter==3` inside the while loop

This can also be done in this way

```
import sys
password = input("Enter password : ")
for __ in range(2):     # loop thrice
    if (password=="Test"):
        break           #user has enterd correct password so break
    password = input("Incorrect, try again : ")
else:
    print ("Locked out")
    sys.exit(1)

#You can put your normal code that is supposed to be
# executed after the correct password is entered
print ("Correct password is entered :)")
#Do whatever you want here
```

An even better way is to wrap this password-checking thing into a function.

```
import sys
def checkPassword():
    password = input("Enter password : ")
    for __ in range(2):
        if (password=="Test"):
            return True
        password = input("Incorrect, try again : ")
    else:
        print ("Locked out")
        return False

if (checkPassword()):
    #continue doing you main thing
    print ("Correct password entered successfully")
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But is there something to fill in where you put the underscore or not (I'm a noobie sorry), but it also does shut the program down any reasons why other than the blank space.

Comment: @AmirBreakableTv no there is nothing fill there, that is how a for loop is used in python and if the variable is not needed then `__`(double underscore) is used. If you do not type the password correctly in three attempts it shuts down (as you wanted). If it is entered correctly , you can add other statements that need to be executed after the last `else` block. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @Grupad Mamadapur Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Move your counter check into the while loop.

Also use [getpass](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/getpass.html) for getting password input in python :)

```
import sys
import getpass

counter = 1
password = getpass.getpass("Enter Password: ")
while password != "Test":
  counter = counter + 1
  password = getpass.getpass("Incorrect, try again: ")
  if counter == 3:
    print("Locked Out")
    sys.exit(1)
print("Logged on!")
```

Comment: it says this :  Warning (from warnings module): line 101
    return fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal.
Warning: Password input may be echoed.

Comment: That is because you are using IDLE editor, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17520292/is-there-easy-way-to-prevent-echo-from-input. Your marker will not use IDLE for marking I presume and my advice to you is you is not use IDLE either ;)

Comment: Ok thanks I'm still a bit confused on how to counteract this I did check the link but can just show a screenshot to me of the code to work in the IDLE please it would be MUCH appreciated to help since I'm new to Python (or programming). All the best :)

Comment: It's still not exiting the program

Comment: I think your definition of existing the program is different... Do you want to close the whole terminal/console window? Because you can literally test it in that link and it exits the program..

Comment: Yeah I want to close the whole terminal

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34389322/how-to-exit-linux-terminal-using-python-script